# Display Text on Image Hover (Images Inline)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, position, themes

Here is a link to my [codepen](http://codepen.io/ericshio/pen/oLawgd).

I want the text to be centered both vertically and horizontally on the image. I also want the text to not be visible unless you are hovering over the image. I think that is the hardest part, but I haven't even gotten that far.

I know it clearly doesn't work, but it is the closest I can get to the layout I am looking for. Any advice? Wrap both the h3 and img in a div possibly?

HTML:

```
<div class="blog-posts">

<h3>Post 1</h3>
<img class="attachment-post-thumbnail" src="http://media3.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2015_50/1312506/151122-donald-trump-smiling-956a_6d624dc0061bbd1233cc33461649ea73.nbcnews-fp-1200-800.jpg" />


<h3>Post 2</h3>
<img class="attachment-post-thumbnail" src="http://media3.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2015_50/1312506/151122-donald-trump-smiling-956a_6d624dc0061bbd1233cc33461649ea73.nbcnews-fp-1200-800.jpg" />

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.blog-posts h3 {
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.attachment-post-thumbnail {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.3%;
    height: auto;
}

.attachment-post-thumbnail:hover {
   -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```